# Why would a page appear in Google Analytics with 0 pageviews?

Tags: google-analytics

Our google analytics site shows pages speeds (i.e. /User/1020120) with specific dates (19 March, 20 seconds to load the page).

But the Page Views column is always 0 for those pages.  How can the pageView column be 0 when the page has clearly loaded and indicated how long its load time was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if google fetches your site, it doesnt count as a hit. Ergo, they crawl your site, test the pagespeeds (and all the other things they do) without a visitor actually being there.

They combine this info with Google Analytics ét voilá.

Comment: I have to add that Google Analytics is far from perfect. It does some rather weird things from time to time and counts bot activity far more than people think while missing valid users for a variety of reasons. I do not want to say that it is impossible to track users vs. bots. But Google seems to be behind the curve these days. Your issue may have something to do with these oddities as Google shifts how it measures visits.

Comment: That's very interesting, Martijn. Can google crawl behind a login page though?

Comment: Nope, that would be scary stuff. G has more or less the same access to pages as users do

Comment: Thanks. Very strange, as those pages are behind the firewall.